# Why <br> and <hr> tag don't work in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

The `<br>` and `<hr>` tags don't work in PhpStorm and when I'm running my `index.php` file in PhpStorm whit this code :

```
<?php
$a=10;
echo "This is $a";
echo "\n";
echo 'This is $a';
echo "\n";
echo "<hr>";
echo "<br>";
print "This is $a";
?>
```

I'm getting this in console:

```
This is 10
This is $a
<hr><br>This is 10
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `Content-Type: text/plain;` ?

Comment: `echo 'This is $a';` should be `echo "This is $a";`. Anything in single quotes is not parsed as php. There must be some auto escaping going on to prevent the HTML tags from rendering as HTML.

Comment: what is that? i have just started php learning 10minutes ago and i dont anything @CD001

Comment: yeah i know that and im just testing single quotes but problem is <br> and <hr> tags @Gavin

Comment: It's the default document type in the HTTP header; if your page/server is serving that page as plain text rather than HTML then your tags will just be treated literally as plain text. Try adding `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');` at the top of your document, immediately after the opening `<?php`

Comment: PHPStorm is an editor not a web browser and a console is a different animal. View that file in a browser and it should work as expected if a webserver/PHP is installed. However, if PHPStorm does have a previewer, then that could be a different ballgame.

Comment: so how can i change it in php storm? my file contain that code i posted @CD001

Comment: @Fred-ii- ... \*blinks\* ... it can't be **that** simple surely? :D

Comment: @CD001 *lmho!* - Love that "blinks" thing *lol* - It could very well be. *Magic* does have a tendency to "just happen" in its *crazy way*.

Comment: thanks men @Fred-ii-

Comment: @AmirPanahandeh *prego* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's reserved for those moments when you realise you've missed something so mind-bogglingly obvious that all you can do is stand there and blink like a confused cartoon character!

Comment: @CD001 So, I have my choice of character to choose from then! Ok... I'll pick *Daffy Duck*, because he's just so, well... "daffy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHPStorm console is show you your *exact* output. And It's accurate.

The `<hr>` and `<br>` tags are HTML. In the console you'll see them just like this.

When you load your page in a web browser those HTML tags will display as a horizontal rule and a blank line, as you expect.

See here for more info about the different options PHPStorm provides for running your PHP code:

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/running-php-applications.html

Comment: expect to have something from the OP saying something like: *"So how do I install a webserver with PHP?"* type of thang ;-) *Wait for it...*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Indeed. That's why I just added a link to the jetbrains docs, which includes instructions on using the built-in PHP server. Think that'll help?

Comment: *Ah, benissimo!* ;-) - si.

Comment: i have installed wampp with php7 but when im running in phpstorm in chrome it give error 404. why? @jszobody

Comment: @AmirPanahandeh See here: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/php-built-in-web-server.html. I can't really troubleshoot WAMPP for you in the comment section, but that should help you run things from PHPStorm.