# Html tag not working in php

Tags: php

I have started learning php. So far i have been using the notepad to run the php codes. Recently I just downloaded phpstorm. In this ide, when I use html tags, it just gets printed out. The break tags inside echo are not printing new lines. it prints `"<br>"` For example:

```
$food = array('Pasta'=>1, 'Burger'=>2, 'Noodles'=>3, 'Rice'=>4);
ksort($food);
foreach($food as $keyname => $valName){           
    echo $valName.$keyname."<br>";            
}
```

this becomes the output:

```
2Burger<br>3Noodles<br>1Pasta<br>4Rice<br>
```

I went to the filetype and changed assigned *.html5 to php. Still the same outcome. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are your HTML tags, you are talking about?

Comment: show screenshots of your script and output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why <br> and <hr> tag don't work in PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945426/why-br-and-hr-tag-dont-work-in-phpstorm)

Comment: Thanks Sean. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to print each time in new line, you can use `"\n"`..e.g.

```
<?php

       $food = array('Pasta'=>1, 'Burger'=>2, 'Noodles'=>3, 'Rice'=>4);
       ksort($food);
       foreach($food as $keyname => $valName){           
           echo $valName.$keyname."\n";            
       }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
    $food = array('Pasta'=>1, 'Burger'=>2, 'Noodles'=>3, 'Rice'=>4);
ksort($food);
foreach($food as $keyname => $valName){           
    echo $valName.$keyname."<br/>";            
}
?>
```